# How to do a line break in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

i used FPDF to print something on a pdf inside a table.

```
$this->Cell(  $subject, 1, 0, 'R', $fill);
```

It works fine.But when the cell is not enough to print the data,the rest of the data  will be moved to another cell.
But i need   rest print inside the same  cell(line break).

[image]

Comment: `\n` is a linebreak. It works with PDFlib. I suppose it works with fpdf too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,This will help you

```
    $this->MultiCell(  $subject, 1, 0, 'R', $fill);
```

Read full documentation [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)

[Example](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php)

Comment: if i add this entire design wiil be failed

Comment: i upload  a image plz watch